# python store string to array not characters

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I tried to store bunch of strings to an array and at the end print out the array, however it print out as a long list of characters. here is my code:

```
user_with_no_records = [""]
for user_test_docs in json_data['results']:
   ... do something here ...
   user_with_no_records.extend(user_test_docs['userId'].replace("'", '"'))
...
pprint(user_with_no_records)
```

instead of print out :

```
"1234-4a20-47c0-b23c-a35a", "53dd-4120-4249-b4f6-ebe2"
```

it print out

```
"1","2","3","4","-","a","2","0"....
```

Comment: You meant to append, not extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.extend(b)` is for extending list `a` by **concatenating another sequence** `b` onto it.   When `b` is a string, and you force it to be interpreted as a sequence, it is interpreted as a sequence of individual characters.  A simple example of this is:

```
>>> b = 'Hello'
>>> list(b)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Instead, you clearly want to do `a.append(b)`,  i.e. insert the entire string `b` as a single new item at the end of `a`.